# Calling MS Azure speech recognition with Kivy app

Tags: python, azure, loops, kivy, speech-recognition

I'm building a Python app with Kivy 2.0.0. I want to access Kivy's loop and call speech recognition every now and then. Speech recognition begins after you press a button and ends after pressing another. This speech recognition then stores its result into one variable (result) and displays it on the screen to a label, the text of which is defined as term_text.

I wrote this code, which I anticipated will work, but it won't. Could you help me out, please?
This is error I get...

File "string", line 22, in module
TypeError: listen() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dt'

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.core import text 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

speech_key, service_region = "", "uksouth"
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
speech_config.speech_recognition_language="en-US"
speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config)

Builder.load_string(""" 
<w1>
    BoxLayout:
    
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        spacing: 50
        padding: 50

        Label:
            id: label1
            text: root.term_text
            bold: True
            size_hint: (3, 3)
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Listen to me now!"
            background_normal: 'none'
            background_color: (0, 64/255, 77/255)
            on_press: root.listen()

        Button:
            id: button2
            text: "Stop listening to me"
            background_normal: 'none'
            background_color: (0, 64/255, 77/255)
            on_press: root.stop()

""")

result = ""

def stop_cb(evt):
    print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
    speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
    global done
    done = True

def collectResult(evt):

    global result 
    result += evt.result.text

class w1(Widget):
    term_text = StringProperty()
    evt = " "


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(w1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.term_text = "terminal"

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.listen, 2)

  def listen(self, dt):

        self.term_text = "Listening..."
    
        speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: collectResult(evt))
        speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STARTED: 
        {}'.format(evt)))
        speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STOPPED 
        {}'.format(evt)))
        speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('CANCELED {}'.format(evt)))

        speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
        speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)
        speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()




    def stop(self):

        stop_cb()
    
        self.term_text = " {} ".format(result)


class DaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return w1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DaApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states:

> listen() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dt'

So you just need to provide a `dt` argument. Try changing:

```
on_press: root.listen()
```

to:

```
on_press: root.listen(0)
```